# Laravel Livewire Multiple Category Filter not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to make simple filtering with livewire in laravel but got stuck on the multiple category filters.

```
// Filters
public $filter = [
    "title" => "",
    "rangeFrom" => "",
    "rangeTo" => "",
    "order_field" => "order_by_name_asc",
    "selectedCat" => [],
];
// method of query
else if(!empty($this->filter['selectedCat'])) {
        $categories = explode(',', $this->filter['selectedCat']);

        $products = Product::where('category_id',
                    function ($query) use ($categories) {
                                $query->whereIn('category_id', $categories);
                            })->limit($this->loadAmount)
                                ->get();
    }
// html[![enter image description here][1]][1]
<p class="mt-4">Catgegories</p>
    @foreach ($categories as $cat)
    <div class="flex" wire:key="{{ $cat->id }}">
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{ $cat->title }}"
                class="h-4 w-4 text-gray-700 border rounded mr-2"
                wire:model="filter.selectedCat"
                value="{{ $cat->id }}">
        <label for="{{ $cat->title }}">{{ $cat->title }}</label>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

The final result in the picture below...
[image]

Comment: Just a tip, if you are binding to a property don't need the value att -> value="{{ $cat->id }}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're after can be achieved by binding to a `dynamic` element in your `selectedCat` nested array.

```html
wire:model="filter.selectedCat.{{ $cat->id }}"
```

What this does is add an element to your array where the `key` is the `id` of the `category` and `value` is true, or false once it is unselected. The array `keys` can then be used to determine which `categories` to filter on, just need to remove the elements with a `false` value.

**Blade file**

```html
<div>
    @foreach ($this->categories as $category)
        <div class="flex items-center space-x-4 mb-2" wire:key="{{ $category->id }}">
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ $category->title }}" name="{{ $category->title }}"
                wire:model="filters.categories.{{ $category->id }}" />
            <label for="{{ $category->title }}">{{ $category->title }}</label>
        </div>
    @endforeach

    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4">
        @foreach ($this->results as $result)
            <div>{{ $result->title }} ({{ $result->category->title }})</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

**Component**

```php
public $filters = [
    'categories' => [],
];

public function getCategoriesProperty()
{
    return Category::all();
}

public function getResultsProperty()
{
    if (empty($this->filters['categories'])) {
        return Product::all();
    }

    // this is where we remove the categories with a false value
    $this->filters['categories'] = array_filter($this->filters['categories']);

    return Product::whereIn('category_id', array_keys($this->filters['categories']))->get();
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.category-filter');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It is working but whenever I uncheck the category it showing no Products I also tried using `if(!empty($this->filters['categories']))` not working

Comment: Your logic is incorrect, have a look at my example again.

Comment: Yes that's what I am telling you according to your logic it should working when there are no categories checked but it shows no products

Comment: @AhmadHassan What you have in your comment above is not what I put in my example. The example works. If there are no categories selected then display all products.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. Please update your question with the exact code you're using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233382/discussion-between-ahmad-hassan-and-peppermintology).

Comment: Hello, @AhmadHassan have you able to fix this? Thank you

Comment: @Jeano I am afraid not...

Comment: @AhmadHassan you need to first remove the false value and then check if $this->filter is empty

Answer (score 0):

**First we remove the categories with a false value**

```
public function getResultsProperty()
{

// First we remove the categories with a false value
$this->filters['categories'] = array_filter($this->filters['categories']);

if (empty($this->filters['categories'])) {
    return Product::all();
}

return Product::whereIn('category_id', array_keys($this->filters['categories']))->get();
```

}